# Improving a TCP communication between Python and C# programs

Tags: python, c#, stream, tcp

I have been using a TCP communications between Python and C# program. Python side (server) runs on a raspberry pi 4 and C# side (client) runs on my computer. RPi and PC connected over Wi-Fi. I have a class in python to listen selected port:

```py
class ListenPort:
    def __init__(self, port: int, event_handler=None, delay: float = 0.004):
        self.__port = port

        # other
        self.__stop_thread = False
        self.out_string = 'null'
        self.out_bytes = b'null'

        self.__sct = None
        self.__thread = None

        self.__event_handler = event_handler
        self.__delay = delay

    def event_call(self):
        if self.__event_handler is not None:
            self.__event_handler()

    def start_listening(self):
        self.__thread = Thread(target=self.listening, args=())
        self.__thread.start()

    def listening(self):
        self.__sct = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
        self.__sct.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.__sct.bind(('0.0.0.0', self.__port))
        self.__sct.listen(1)

        connection_out = self.__sct.accept()[0].makefile('rwb')
        handler = SplitFrames(connection_out)
        while not self.__stop_thread:
            try:
                handler.write("Waiting for data".encode("utf-8"))
                self.out_string = handler.read().decode("utf-8")

                self.event_call()

                time.sleep(self.__delay)
            except (ConnectionAbortedError, BrokenPipeError) as e:
                exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                file_name = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
                # logging
                break
        self.__sct.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        self.__sct.close()

    def reset_out(self):
        self.out_string = 'null'
        self.out_bytes = b'null'

    def stop_listening(self):
        self.__stop_thread = True
        self.reset_out()
        if self.__sct is not None:
            try:
                self.__sct.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            except (OSError, Exception) as e:
                exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                file_name = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
                # logging
            if self.__thread is not None:
                st_time = time.time()
                while self.__thread.is_alive():
                    if time.time() - st_time > 1:
                        try:
                            self.__sct.close()
                        except (OSError, Exception) as e:
                            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                            file_name = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
                            # logging
                        st_time = time.time()
```

and a class `SplitFrames` that I took somewhere, that helps me with working with TCP on low level:

```py
class SplitFrames(object):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        self.stream = io.BytesIO()
        self.count = 0
        self.name = ""

    def write_camera(self, buf, name):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            # Start of new frame; send the old one's length
            # then the data
            size = self.stream.tell()
            if size > 0:
                nm = self.name.encode("utf-8")
                self.connection.write(struct.pack('<L', len(nm)))
                self.connection.flush()
                self.connection.write(nm)
                self.connection.flush()
                self.connection.write(struct.pack('<L', size))
                self.connection.flush()
                self.stream.seek(0)
                self.connection.write(self.stream.read(size))
                self.count += 1
                self.stream.seek(0)
                self.connection.flush()
        self.stream.write(buf)
        self.name = name

    def write(self, buf):
        self.connection.write(struct.pack('<L', len(buf)))
        self.connection.flush()
        self.connection.write(buf)
        self.count += 1
        self.connection.flush()

    def read(self) -> bytearray:
        data_len = struct.unpack('<L', self.connection.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        return self.connection.read(data_len)
```

On the C# side I have a class to talk to selected port:

```cs
namespace mynamespacehere
{
    public class TalkPort
    {
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnNeedToSetMessage;

        public string OutString = "";
        private bool stopThread = false;
        private IPEndPoint ipPoint;

        private Socket sct;
        public Thread thread;

        internal TalkPort(IPEndPoint ipPoint)
        {
            this.ipPoint = ipPoint;
        }

        private void SetUpSocket()
        {
            sct = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sct.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        }

        public void StartTalking()
        {
            OutString = "";
            this.stopThread = false;
            SetUpSocket();
            thread = new Thread(() => { Talking(); });
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void Talking()
        {

            sct.Connect(ipPoint);
            while (!this.stopThread)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (OnNeedToSetMessage != null)
                    {
                        OnNeedToSetMessage(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    }

                    string outString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(FuncadHelper.GetInputBytes(sct));

                    if (outString == string.Empty)
                    {
                        sct.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        sct.Close();
                        try
                        {
                            SetUpSocket();
                            sct.Connect(ipPoint);
                        }
                        catch (SocketException exx)
                        {
                            // logging
                        }
                    }

                    FuncadHelper.SetOutputBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(OutString), sct);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // logging
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsAlive()
        {
            if (thread != null)
                return thread.IsAlive;
            return false;
        }

        public void StopTalking()
        {
            this.stopThread = true;
            try
            {
                sct.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sct.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // logging
                try
                {
                    sct.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e2)
                {
                    // logging
                }
            }
            ResetOut();
        }

        public void ResetOut()
        {
            OutString = "";
        }
    }
}
```

and the class that helps me with working with TCP on low level:

```cs
namespace mynamespacehere
{
    public class FuncadHelper
    {
        public static byte[] GetInputBytes(Socket clientSocket)
        {
            byte[] rcvLenBytes = new byte[4];
            clientSocket.Receive(rcvLenBytes);
            UInt32 rcvLen = BytesToInt(rcvLenBytes);

            byte[] rcvBytes;
            byte[] clientData;
            List<byte> rcvBytesList = new List<byte>();
            int totalBytes = 0;
            while (totalBytes < rcvLen)
            {
                if (rcvLen - totalBytes < 262144)
                {
                    clientData = new byte[rcvLen - totalBytes];
                }
                else
                {
                    clientData = new byte[262144];
                }
                int bytesReceived = clientSocket.Receive(clientData);
                rcvBytesList.AddRange(clientData.Take(bytesReceived).ToArray());
                totalBytes += bytesReceived;
            }
            rcvBytes = rcvBytesList.ToArray();

            return rcvBytes;
        }

        public static void SetOutputBytes(byte[] data, Socket clientSocket)
        {
            byte[] toSendBytes = data;
            byte[] toSendLenBytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);
            clientSocket.Send(toSendLenBytes);
            clientSocket.Send(toSendBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

And the main problem is that when I want to listen to about 10 ports the delay between two sending of data on each port is over 50 ms. There is also a port that conducts a video from camera so delay on the port is over 800 ms. Is there a way to speed up TCP connection using my code?

Answer (score 3):

Why use Python on one side and C# on the other - why not C# on both sides? That reduces cognitive load, among other benefits.

Don't use double underscores for private members; use single underscores. Double underscores are for name mangling.

`ListenPort` is not a great name because it's not a port; it *uses* a port to listen for data. Consider instead `SocketListener`, `CameraListener` or whatever.

`event_handler` should be hinted as `Optional`.

`ListenPort` should be made a context manager that, on exit, joins the thread and closes the socket.

Good use of `struct` and good idea to prefix your stream elements with lengths. Not such a good idea to intersperse your stream writes with `flush()`. Buffering exists for a reason, and you should rely on it to do the right thing. Flush only once, at the end of your message.

Surely `Thread(() => { Talking(); });` is not necessary and you can just pass a reference `Talking` directly to the `Thread` constructor.

Comment: There is no way to use C# on both of the sides. Thanks for such a detailed analysis of the code.

Comment: @crackanddie you can run C# code on **Raspberry Pi** since the release of the **.net core** you can run .net code latterly anywhere as you like ... here is a simple article show how to [Install and use Microsoft Dot NET 6 with the Raspberry Pi](https://www.petecodes.co.uk/install-and-use-microsoft-dot-net-6-with-the-raspberry-pi/)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest profiling, but if I had to guess I'd put my money on this line in the `FuncadHelper` (also what is that name??)

```
List<byte> rcvBytesList = new List<byte>();
```

You're making a new list **every single time** you try to get input bytes. I believe this triggers garbage collection every time you exit scope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to profile the code and change the line ```List<byte> rcvBytesList = new List<byte>();```

Answer (score 1):

The `struct` library is intended to pack entire structs. If you decide to rather encode `int`s into bytes, use [`int.to_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=to_bytes#int.to_bytes).

However, it seems that you rather want to dump elements of a C# struct onto a stream here:

```py
def write_camera(self, buf, name):
    if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
        # Start of new frame; send the old one's length
        # then the data
        size = self.stream.tell()
        if size > 0:
            nm = self.name.encode("utf-8")
            self.connection.write(struct.pack('<L', len(nm)))
            self.connection.flush()
            self.connection.write(nm)
            self.connection.flush()
            self.connection.write(struct.pack('<L', size))
            self.connection.flush()
            self.stream.seek(0)
            self.connection.write(self.stream.read(size))
            self.count += 1
            self.stream.seek(0)
            self.connection.flush()
    self.stream.write(buf)
    self.name = name
```

So, use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library accordingly:

```py
def write_camera(self, buf, name):
    if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
        # Start of new frame; send the old one's length
        # then the data
        size = self.stream.tell()
        if size > 0:
            name = self.name.encode("utf-8")
            struct.pack_into(f'<L{len(name)}sL', self.connection, 0, len(name), name, size)
            ...
```